# Cannot use hat in self-made command

Tags: math-mode, accents, subscripts

Here's a minimal example of what is not working for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{a_#1}

\begin{document}
$\foo{\hat{1}}$
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong in my command definition, or is something else going wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

Your current definition *assumes* that your argument to `\foo` will be a single token. Hover, `\hat{1}` is not a single token. Wrap the subscript in braces to allow multiple tokens to be properly set as a subscript:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{a_{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\foo{\hat{1}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that kind-of makes sense. Why does \hat{1} not count as a single token though? Things like $\foo{\mathbf{1}}$ do work, so what's the difference exactly?

Comment: @Joeytje50: It depends on how the macro is written as some are more [robust](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764).